# Is there a way to access the properties of a class created in one function from another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, global

Is there a way to access the properties of a class created in one function from another function ?

```
class Component(object):
    Name = ''
    Num = 100

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

def one():
    exec('AAA' + '=Component()')
    AAA.Name = 'AAA'
    AAA.Num = AAA.Num * 2
    print '1', AAA.Name, AAA.Num

def two():
    print '2', AAA.Name, AAA.Num

one()
two()
```

I get a "NameError: global name 'AAA' is not defined"

Comment: Sure, the right way to do this would be to just return `AAA` from your `one` function and pass it in as a parameter into your `two` function.

Comment: What's the point of that overridden `__setattr__` method? It does precisely nothing.

Comment: And what's the point of that `exec` call, rather than just instantiating the object directly?

Comment: This was just an example. the real object has close to 50 properties, and I want to use object notation in function two !

Comment: Even with 50 properties you don't need to override `setattr` or use `exec`. And as machineyearning says, if you want to use it in function two you need to pass it there.

Comment: By the way, you aren't creating a class in your functions, you are creating instances.

Comment: Thew reason for the exec is that at run time 'AAA' might be any string.

Answer (score 0):

Class level attributes belong to the class and are therefore shared among all instances of that class.

If you want different instances of the class to have different `name` and `num` attributes (by the way, you should be using lowercased attribute names for instances), you should add them as instance attributes. You can access the class attributes using the class name (e.g. `Component.NUM`).

```
class Component(object):
    NAME = ''
    NUM = 100

    def __init__(self, name, num):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num

print Component.NAME  # ''
print Component.NUM  # 100

c = Component('AAA', Component.NUM * 2)
print c.name  # 'AAA'
print c.num  # 200
```

Answer (score 0):

**One possible solution:**

Create a global list(tuple, dict or any proper data structure you want) and add the instance to the list in function one, then get the instance from the list in function two.

However, global variables are not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate `class` outside the `function` and use that class instance with in the function. Below is the code:

```
>>> class Component(object):
...     Name = ''
...     Num = 100
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
...
>>> # Moved object creation to outside of func
... exec('AAA' + '=Component()')
>>>
>>> def one():
...     AAA.Name = 'AAA'
...     AAA.Num = AAA.Num * 2
...     print '1', AAA.Name, AAA.Num
...
>>> def two():
...     print '2', AAA.Name, AAA.Num
...     AAA.Name = 'BBB'
...     AAA.Num = AAA.Num * 2
...     print '3', AAA.Name, AAA.Num
...
>>> one()
1 AAA 200
>>> two()
2 AAA 200
3 BBB 400
```